# mutiple function on a single button click

Tags: android, button

> i have a button i want three functionality for that 
>   on first click it start recording sound .on second click it will stop on third click it show three options (play sound,record new,delete sound) how can i implement this action
>   help

```
 k=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    k.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a class level variable and determine what click has transpired. The difficulty in this approach is defining when to reset the value.

```
private int _clicks = 0;

k = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
k.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int count = ++_clicks;

        if(count == 1)
             //do whatever
        if(count == 2)
             //do whatever
        if(count == 3)
             //do whatever
    }
});
```

A better approach would to simply assign multiple handlers to multiple buttons and perform the action needed for the button. This would allow you to define a 1:1 relationship and will make your code much more manageable down the road.

**EDIT**: To record sound there are [plenty of examples](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/) on the web.

```
  public class AudioRecorder {

  final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
  final String path;

  /**
   * Creates a new audio recording at the given path (relative to root of SD card).
   */
  public AudioRecorder(String path) {
    this.path = sanitizePath(path);
  }

  private String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
      path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
      path += ".3gp";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
  }

  /**
   * Starts a new recording.
   */
  public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
  }

  /**
   * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
   */
  public void stop() throws IOException {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
  }

}
```

Comment: can u say how i record a sound in the first click

Comment: @user1103284 Edit added, reference to recording sound

Comment: can you give me a example project of sound recording

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to have three different onClickListeners. take a look at this code:

in your onCreate:

```
...
button.setOnClickListener(playListener);
...
```

create methods for `play()`, `stop()`, and `showOption()` anywhere in your activity, and this:

```
    OnClickListener playListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            play();
            v.setOnClickListener(stopListener);
        }
    };

    OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stop();
            v.setOnClickListener(showOptionListener);
        }
    };

    OnClickListener showOptionListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showOption();
        }
    };
```